# Cant find CSS & JS files with excluded templates JAVA + Spring

Tags: javascript, java, css, spring, freemarker

i am using spring for my project and i excluded all template-files to another "html-Project". I did it because i can do changes without any redeployment and for me its ways clearer. it works fine and the spring application find all templates. But now, the template cant find any css or js files. The template try to search the files in my spring-project but they are included in the html project. How i can fix it? I need something like a relative path i think.

Projects
**SpringApp**
---- lib
---- src
-------- main
------------ java
---------------- com.example.test
-------------------- controller
------------------------ ShowIndex.java
------------ resources
------------ webapp
-------- test

**HTML-Templates**
---- lib
---- src
-------- main
------------ java
------------ resources
------------ templates
---------------- css
-------------------- bootstrap.min.css
---------------- js
-------------------- bootstrap.min.js
---------------- images
---------------- index.ftl
---------------- test.ftl
-------- test

Content of ShowIndex.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(ModelMap model) {
    model.put("prename", "Hans-Peter");

    return "index";
}
```

HeaderContent of index.ftl

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/zeus.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Any ideas?

I use:
JAVA
Spring WebMVC
Freemarker as TemplateEngine

Comment: Need to see the relevant paths and directory structure. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Put your `css`, `js`, `images` to the `src/main/webapps` folder, separate from the templates `ftl` files.

**EDIT**

With Servlet 3.0 you have another choice, but maybe not work in all containers...

1. create a `META-INF/resources` folder
2. put all you resources `js, css, images` and etc to this folder
3. and 'jar' it.

for example I created a `assembly.xml` file for automate this work

```
<assembly>
    <id>bin</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>target/classes</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.class</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/DefaultController.class</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>WebContent</directory>
            <outputDirectory>META-INF/resources</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>/WEB-INF/jsp/**</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>  

        <fileSet>
            <directory>WebContent</directory>
            <outputDirectory>META-INF/resources</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>js/**</include>
                <include>plugins/**</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

This file works when use maven building `mvn package`.

*PS*:

In maven `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    ...

    <build>
        ...

        <plugins>
            ...

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
    ...

</project>
```

Comment: my templates arent in the same project. if i paste the css and js files into my spring project, i have to deploy all css/js changes. i think ur answer would works fine but its not a real solution =/

Comment: But its still the same i think. I have to redeploy my CSS changes right?

Comment: The resources in your `abc.jar:/META_INFO/resources/xyz.css` can direct accessed by user, e.g. `http://example.com/xyz.css`, you don't need pull out and paste to you webapp's folder.

Comment: it doesnt work, the css/js files are now available in my jar file but i have to redeploy and if its possible i would like to place the css files in my HTML project, not in my spring project

Comment: sorry for incorrectness in previous comment, it must be `/META-INF`  as is in the answer post